# In place Tokenization of std::string into a map of Key Value

Tags: c++, string, c++11, tokenize

In C the delimiters can be replaced by Nulls and a map of char* -> char* with a comparison function would work.

I am trying to figure out the fastest possible way to do this in Modern C++ . The idea is to avoid Copying characters in the Map.

```
std::string sample_string("name=alpha;title=something;job=nothing");
```

to

```
std::map<std::string,std::string> sample_map;
```

Without copying characters.

It's ok to lose original input string.

Comment: Well, `string` owns its resources, so you can't not copy.

Comment: Use `shared_ptr`.

Comment: A better way than `shared_ptr`, which incurs a non-trivial overhead, is to use something like `std::string_view` (part of C++17 draft but seems like some compilers already shipped it as an experimental feature). Other alternatives are `boost::string_view`, `boost::string_ref` and `gsl::string_span`.

Comment: As other says std::string owns its resources. If you want to get fancy use Boost.Tokenizer with basic_string_ref to prevent copying. Eventually c++ will adopt basic_string_view.

Answer (score 1):

Two std::strings cannot point to the same underlying bytes, so no it's not possible to do with strings.

To avoid coping bytes, you could to use iterators:

```
struct Slice {
  string::iterator begin, end;
  bool operator < (const& Slice that) const {
    return lexicographical_compare(begin, end, that.begin, that.end);
  }
};

std::map<Slice,Slice> sample_map;
```

And beware that if you modify the original string, all the iterators will be invalid.